# Manually save a many to many relation in Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony-1.4

I have just created a new project with a many-to-many relation (User-Group) and the code below.

As you can guess in the code I'm trying to assign manually groups to a user, but it doesn't assign it anything...any idea?

```
User:
  columns:
    id: 
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    username:
      type: string(255)
    password:
      type: string(255)
  attributes:
    export: all 
    validate: true

Group:
  tableName: group_table
  columns:
    id: 
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
  relations:
    Users:
      foreignAlias: Groups
      class: User
      refClass: GroupUser

GroupUser:
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
  relations:
    Group:
      foreignAlias: GroupUsers
    User:
      foreignAlias: GroupUsers
```

The code is this:

```
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->find(1);

    $groups = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Group')->findAll();

    $user->setGroups($groups);

    $user->save();
    $this->forward('default', 'module');
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$groups` actually contains results? If this is empty, presumably `$user` would be unchanged.

Comment: @halfer Hi halfer, I created two groups. var_dump(count($groups)); returns int(2).

Comment: OK, carry on debugging. I don't use Doctrine (Propel for me) but maybe `$user->save()` returns a boolean success? Check the docs and/or the library code for that. I'd personally put a temporary `exit()` after the save, and ensure all warnings/error reporting is turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining the relation in the User entity too (and don't using foreingAlias in Groups). Also use the **local** and **foreign** fields.
So, schema.yml should look like:

```
User:
  ...
  relations:
    Groups:
      class: Group
      refClass: GroupUser
      local: user_id
      foreign: group_id

Group:
  ...
  relations:
    Users:
      class: User
      refClass: GroupUser
      local: group_id 
      foreign: user_id
```

If that doesn't work, I think you can set the groups with the Doctrine "link" method.
See Record.php (probably in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine folder)

Example:

```
$groups_ids = array();
foreach($groups as $group) $groups_ids[] = $group->getId();
$user->link('Groups',$groups_ids);
```

Also, if you are trying only to add instances to that relation (and you hate the person who will fix your code in the future) you can create N-GroupUsers
Example:

```
foreach($groups as $group) {
    $ug = new GroupUser();
    $ug->setUserId($user->getId());
    $ug->setGroupId($user->getId());
    $ug->save();
}
```

Please, use the first option and let me know if any of this works for you!

Comment: When many to many is setup correctly and cascade persist is enabled (default), you should be able to use the first option (that is `$user->setGroups($groups);`) and not bother about the ref class